# How to remove the entire html element

Tags: angularjs

I have the following list:

[image]

Html code:

```
 <div ng-repeat="alerta in alertas">
          <div class="aa" style="    margin-top: 1px;width: 100%; height: 52px;border-bottom: solid 1px #d4d4d4;">
                <div class="float-left" style="width: 80%;">
                    <a href="#" class="item item-icon-left"  >
                    <i class="icon ion-alert"></i>
                    {{alerta.desc}}
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="float-left divdeletea">
                     <span ng-click="deleteAlert($index)"><img class="imgDelete" src="img/remove-icon.png"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
       </div>
```

But only the text is being deleted see the image below:
[image]

Controller code:

```
$scope.deleteAlert= function(i){
    delete $scope.alertas[i];

}
```

The result I expected would be to delete the entire line:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `delete` keyword is used to remove a property from an object. So assuming you have an object:

```
let object = {name: 'Pete'};
delete object.name; // {}
```

You'd be left with an empty object. I had never thought of using it with an array, but I'm assuming it's replacing the element with `undefined` or something like that, which is still a valid array element.

Anyway, the proper way to remove elements from an array is with the `splice()` method, which takes two arguments, the index and how many elements you want to remove. So:

```
$scope.alertas.splice(index, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

try `splice` to delete the item from the array :

```
$scope.deleteAlert= function(i){
    $scope.alertas.splice(i, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example which may help you:

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []); 
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.alertas = [{desc:"test1"},{desc:"test2"},{desc:"test3"}];
    $scope.addItem = function (val) {
       $scope.alertas.push({desc:$scope.addMe});
    }    
    $scope.removeItem = function (x) {
        $scope.alertas.splice(x, 1);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
{{alertas}}
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="alerta in alertas">{{alerta.desc}} <span ng-click="removeItem($index)">×</span></li>
  </ul>
  <input ng-model="addMe">
  <button ng-click="addItem()">Add</button>
</div>
```